# @Html.EditorFor throwing $ is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik

I have the following Editor Template defined and when I call it from my View it is throwing the *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined* error.

```
@model System.DateTime?

<input id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" title="datepicker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").kendoDatePicker();
</script>
```

In my view I call the editor template as follows

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateHired)
```

I have tried to put the code into a Script section but it is still giving the same error.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").kendoDatePicker();
        });
    </script>
@
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it does not resolve the issue because the javascript code is called within an EditorTemplate and that this EditorTemplate is called from a View. I am not sure what is the proper way to have the javascript code work as my view already contains reference to the jquery library.

Comment: When and where exactly is that error being thrown? Also, your last piece of code wouldn't work since it's commented out

Comment: Make sure jquery is in the `<head>` not at the bottom just before `</body>`

Comment: *my view already contains jquery* - why does your *view* have jquery and not your layout?

Comment: $user14322615: Does the error is thrown on `$("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").kendoDatePicker();` line?

Comment: @freedomn-m jquery has no need to go in the head, it's perfectly fine for it to go in the body

Comment: The duplicate has 45 answers, and the accepted answer lists at least three reasons why the error may be occurring. The question does not have enough information to reproduce the error (the relative locations of the `script` elements that introduce jQuery and that use jQuery), and no indication that any of the 45 answers have been examined or attempted. If you have, [edit] your question with the needed information.

Comment: @Jackdaw: The error is thrown at $(document).ready(function ().

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto: Sorry I copied the commented out code when I pasted into this. I've removed the comment syntax on the section Scripts.

Comment: My View has the Jquery reference because in my Layout I have defined the following the body tag.
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/dist/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

Comment: @user14322615: It might be you forgot to add the main `kendo` UI JS file. See [https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/first-steps](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/first-steps)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if you have code in the body with `<script>$(document)...</script>` then have `<script src="jquery.js">` just before `</body>` then, no, it's not "perfectly fine" and OPs description *will* occur - it's ok if the jquery include is before the script, but the MVC template puts it at the end of the body, so it will give the provided error.

Comment: Comment above `@RenderBody <script src=jquery...` that's your problem - you're trying to run your script with jquery before you've included jquery as your EditorFor gets rendered within RenderBody.  Look at the *rendered html* and you'll see your `<script>$...` code is before `<script src=` - you must include jquery first.  You can either move @RenderBody after `<script src=jquery` (so jquery is in the body, but first as (noted by @CamiloTerevinto it can be in the body) or move it to the `<head>` to you are *sure* it's before you're body based `<script>$...`